# dygraph - Errors parsing date in CSV

Tags: dygraphs

I'm constantly getting these errors even though the date format matches exactly with what dygraph expects:

```
Couldn't parse "2019/01/04 23:59:58" as a date
```

For the life of me I can't see what the problem with the string format is. It appears identical to the documentation which suggests is valid:

```
2009/07/12 12:34:56
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, turns out the string with the date had double quotes around it. Removed the quotes and parsed fine.